# ¿Cómo hacer que mis inputs guarden números decimales (con coma y punto) y enteros?

Tags: javascript, python, django

lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo cálculos y coloco precios en mis inputs, por lo que uso decimales. El problema es que cuando quiero guarda los cálculos al dar click al boton de "Save" no se puede, eso pasa cuando coloco números decimales pero si coloco enteros lo guarda bien. No entiendo porqué pasa esto ya que estoy usando en mi form.py

`'pattern': '[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}'` y `'step': 'any',`

También les comento que  para recoger los valores en JS estoy usando Number.

No sé si tenga algo que ver que cuando escribo el número en mis inputs lo hago con el punto decimal: 1.5

Y cuando hace los cálculos me devuelve el decimal con coma: 1,5

> form.py

```
class PresupuestosParteForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Parte
       fields = ['codigo','quantity','unit_price','total_price','tax_free','comprado_cliente','descripcion','descuento_parte']
       exclude = ['estimate_id']
       widgets = {
           'codigo': forms.TextInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control',
                   'id': 'id__form-0-codigo',
               }
           ),
           'quantity': forms.NumberInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control-quantity',
                   'id':'id__form-0-quantity',
               }
           ),
           'unit_price': forms.NumberInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control-unit-price',
                   'id': 'id__form-0-unit_price',
                   'onchange': 'multiplicar()',
                   'pattern': '[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}',
                   'step':'any',
               }
           ),
           'total_price': forms.NumberInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control-total-price',
                   'id': 'id__form-0-total_price',
                   'pattern': '[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}',
                   'step': 'any',

               }
           ),
           'tax_free': forms.CheckboxInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-check-input',
                   'onclick': 'taxes_free(multiplicar())',
                   'id': 'id__form-0-tax_free',
               }
           ),
           'comprado_cliente': forms.CheckboxInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-check-input',
                   'onclick': 'taxes_free(descuentoParte())',
                   'id': 'id__form-0-comprado_cliente',
               }
           ),
           'descripcion': forms.TextInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control',
                   'id': 'id__form-0-descripcion',
               }
           ),
           'descuento_parte': forms.NumberInput(
               attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control',
                   'id': 'id__form-0-descuento_parte',
                   'onchange': 'descuentoParte(multiplicar())',
               }
           ),
       }
```

> calculos.js

```
   quantity = Number($('#'+quantity).val());
   unit_price = Number($('#'+unit_price).val());
```

> models.py

```
   quantity=models.IntegerField()
   unit_price=models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: ¿Porqué usas `integerField`? Lo suyo sería usar [`floatField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#floatfield)

Comment: No soy experto en python pero que tal si usas `unit_price=models.FloatField()`. Supongo que `IntegerField()` es para números enteros unicamente

Comment: muchas gracias! sirvió :)